# How to give a normal user access only to the /var/log directory Centos7

Tags: linux, centos, centos7

I have a non-admin user in Centos7 to whom I need to give permissions only to access `/var/log` as he needs to write it's own log file mainly supervised.log i'm starting `supervisord` as non root user

I do not want to give him admin access at any cost.

How can I achieve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am thinking two ways:

1. Using `setfacl`:

   ```
    setfacl -m user:username:rwx /var/log
    setfacl -m mask:rwx /var/log
   ```
2. Then using the `sudoers` file:

   ```
    User_Alias     OP = koko

    OP ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /var/log
   ```

Note:

Use `sudo visudo` when editing the `sudoers file`

Answer (score 0):

Look into access control lists and the command setfacl